# Advent of slow steps in CI pipeline in CD environment and minimising their impact

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

Running a *fast* test suite as part of an artifact's CI pipeline is pretty common place. Recently I've also seen encouragement to add *slow* steps to CI pipelines: performance tests, backward compatibility tests, whole environment tests, etc.

In my experience these slow steps have never been made part of the CI pipeline but instead are practiced infrequently and manually.

I can see the benefits but I also struggle fitting them into a continuous delivery environment. Not to think CD is just about pushing code to production in a hurry, but there is a time element to it.

If I had to give it a go I'd set up a fast pipeline that builds a deployable artifact after executing a fast test suite that is deployable to all non-production environments, followed by a slow pipeline that runs in parallel. On completion the slow pipeline would mark the artifact as production deployable and possibly deploy itself to production.

Tooling is key I think, and I haven't come across anything that manages an artifact's deployability lifecycle so far.

I'd like to know what approaches **you** have encountered, in which situations they worked and why, and where didn't they work so well.

Comment: We're currently building Reliza Hub to support this functionality - see my article here for how we run tests on created artifacts and mark them as deployable or not - https://worklifenotes.com/2021/02/03/automated-tests-ci-cd-workflow-with-reliza-hub/

Comment: thanks! I'll give it a read